# Compute time difference according to a condition and for big data with Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

help please...I have data like this:

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring, length
dept = [("A",1,"2020-11-07 23:19:12"), ("A",1,"2020-11-07 23:19:16"), ("A",1,"2020-11-07 23:19:56"), ("A",0,"2020-11-07 23:20:37"), ("A",0,"2020-11-07 23:21:06"), ("A",0,"2020-11-07 23:21:47"), ("A",1,"2020-11-07 23:22:05"), ("A",1,"2020-11-07 23:22:30"),("A",1,"2020-11-07 23:23:00"), ("B",1,"2020-11-07 22:19:12"), ("B",1,"2020-11-07 22:20:10"), ("B",0,"2020-11-07 22:21:31"), ("B",0,"2020-11-07 22:22:01"), ("B",0,"2020-11-07 22:22:45"), ("B",1,"2020-11-07 22:23:52"), ("B",1,"2020-11-07 22:24:10")]
deptColumns = ["Id","BAP","Time"]
deptDF = spark.createDataFrame(data=dept, schema = deptColumns)
deptDF.show()
```

[image: Data Example (I have 60 millions rows like this)]

1. With Pyspark, how to get the time for the first 0 of the first series of zeros for each ID, and get the time of the first 1 just after the same series of zeros.Then make a time_stamp subtraction between the two. Something like this:

[image: Expected result]

This must be done for each series of zeros which compose each ID. Thus, we can have several DeltaTime for the same ID if there are several series of zeros.

Actually, i can compute delta time between consecutive rows:

```
Delta=deptDF.withColumn("DeltaTime",(deptDF.Time.cast("bigint") - lag(deptDF.Time.cast("bigint"),1).over(Window.partitionBy("Id").orderBy("Time")).cast("bigint")))
Delta.show()
```

it-is possible to add any condition to have expected result ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show your efforts. SO is not a work-offloading system.

Comment: Post edited.. check the new version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two columns begin0 and begin1 to help with parsing your data using window functions:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

window = Window.partitionBy('Id').orderBy('Time')
Delta = deptDF.withColumn(
    'begin0',
    (F.lag('BAP').over(window) != 0) & (F.col('BAP') == 0)
).withColumn(
    'begin1',
    (F.lag('BAP').over(window) == 0) & (F.col('BAP') == 1)
).filter(
    'begin0 or begin1'
).withColumn(
    'DeltaTime',
    F.when(
        F.col('BAP') == 0,
        F.date_format(
            (
                F.lead('Time').over(window).cast('timestamp').cast('bigint') -
                F.col('Time').cast('timestamp').cast('bigint')
            ).cast('timestamp'),
           'HH:mm:ss'
       )
    ).otherwise(
        F.lit('00:00:00')
    )
).drop(
    'begin0', 'begin1'
).orderBy(
    'Id','Time'
)

Delta.show()
+---+---+-------------------+---------+
| Id|BAP|               Time|DeltaTime|
+---+---+-------------------+---------+
|  A|  0|2020-11-07 23:20:37| 00:01:28|
|  A|  1|2020-11-07 23:22:05| 00:00:00|
|  B|  0|2020-11-07 22:21:31| 00:02:21|
|  B|  1|2020-11-07 22:23:52| 00:00:00|
+---+---+-------------------+---------+
```